# How to translate number value in a print barcode from XML through XSL to PDF

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to know how it's possible to translate a number value in a print barcode from XML through XSL to PDF.

I have a value on xml like : `<barcode>2019000002520 BLC</barcode>` and I would show on the printed PDF bill the black lines of barcode.

Comment: Can you provide some information on what you have as source and what efforts you made so far ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your xslt runtime...

If you use Java: Apache FOP with Barcode4J-Plugin (http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/fop-ext.html)

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <barcode:barcode
          xmlns:barcode="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns"
          message="my message" orientation="90">
      <barcode:code128>
        <barcode:height>8mm</barcode:height>
      </barcode:code128>
    </barcode:barcode>
  </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:block>
```